# How do I know when a circuit is unsolvable?

Tags: network

[image]

I know 2 formulas for basic cutset and loop, which is a number of equations that need to be solved circuit. But it does not mention when a circuit will be unsolvable. If number of equations become negative, does it mean it is unsolvable?
[image]

Comment: If there are more unknown variables than there are equations, then it is unsolvable.

Comment: Or when the equations lead to a contradiction. The easiest example I could think of is putting two different voltage sources in parallel.

Comment: It's, however, totally unclear what you mean with "number of equations become negative": That's not something a "number of" can do.

Comment: If there is an answer mathematically but the numbers turn out to be not physically realizable (negative resistances, for example).